# Details of creation of accessor methods and ivars with @property and @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, properties

I was trying something out as I was learning about `@property` and `@synthesize`. I thought `@property` created the instance variables and `@synthesize` created the getter and setter methods for it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYPoint : NSObject 
@property int x, y;

-(void) setX: (int) xVar andY: (int) yVar;

@end
```

I didn't synthesize `x` and `y` in my implementation file, but I was wondering why I was allowed to do both:

```
-(void) setX:(int)x {
    x = x;
}

-(void) setY:(int)y {
    y = y;
}
```

but got an error message about undeclared identifiers `x` and `y` when I did this:

```
-(void) setX:(int)xVar andY:(int)yVar {
    x = xVar;
    y = yVar;
}
```

Also, why didn't `-(void) setY:(int)y` and `-(void) setX:(int)x` have to be declared in the interface file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought @property created the instance variables and @synthesize created the getters and setters method for it.

This is not quite correct. The `@property` declaration basically just makes a promise to other classes: "You can ask me for an `int` named `x`, and I will also respond to attempts to give me an `int` to store under that name." The declaration itself doesn't create anything in the class, either methods or an ivar.

It's `@synthesize` that does *both* those things. You can implement your own setter, getter, and ivar yourself, or you can synthesize them (or any combination).

So the reason that you're getting that error when you don't use `@synthesize` is that no ivars have been created, so `x` and `y` aren't names you can use inside the class.

In the first case, you're not doing what you seem to think you're doing. In this method:

```
-(void) setX:(int)x {
    x = x;
}
```

`x` is the name of the parameter, and you're just assigning it to itself. (You can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope. If you *had* created an ivar named `x`, you'd get a compiler warning about the method parameter shadowing the ivar. That means that the parameter name, being the same as the ivar, won't allow you to access the ivar.)

If you change that to:

```
-(void) setX:(int)newX {
    x = newX;
}
```

you'll see the same error about `x` being undeclared.

> Also, why didn't `-(void) setY:(int)y` and `-(void) setX:(int)x` have to be declared in the interface file?

They are declared by the `@property` directive.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are merely assigning your parameter variables the values they already have.  What's happening may make more sense if you change your parameter names:

```
-(void) setX:(int)xVar {
    x = xVar;
}

-(void) setY:(int)yVar {
    y = yVar;
}
```

The error messages should then be consistent.